# Codeigniter return mysql query result to single array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have code like this

```
$mene   = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('+1 days'));
$now    = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$qnow   = $this->db->query("SELECT pilihan,COUNT(pilihan) as total FROM votes WHERE date_create BETWEEN '$now' AND '$mene' GROUP BY pilihan");

$someArray = [];
foreach($qnow->result_array() as $row){
    array_push($someArray, [
    $row['pilihan']   => $row['total']
    ]);
}

$someJSON = json_encode($someArray);
echo $someJSON;
```

And this for result

```
[
  {
    "1": "213"
  },
  {
    "2": "444"
  }
]
```

How to make this result to single array, so result will be

```
[
  {
    "1": "213",
    "2": "444"
  }
]
```

Please help to resolve that, Thank you.

Comment: **WARNING**: This code has some [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is not escaped before being used in the query. Read up on how to use [query bindings](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html) with placeholder values so that data can be properly encoded before being used in the query. Even if the values used here seem harmless, they could be replaced at a later time with those that aren't, creating a hidden, exploitable hole.

Comment: Okay, thank you @tadman , I will check that

Comment: @tadman - I don't see any unescaped user input in his query.

Comment: @shaggy `$now` is interpolated, and although in this contrived example it's not user data, all it takes is switching that with `$now = $_GET['date']` and you're in deep trouble. Sometimes these variables are defined in distant parts of the system and passed in so it's never obvious what is or isn't safe. That's why using placeholder values for everything, regardless of origin, is important.

Comment: @tadman - yes and if you switch `echo $someJSON;` to `echo $config['db']['password'];` you get in trouble too. So there are no SQL injection bugs. There might be, if he change the code.

Comment: @shaggy Which one is more likely to happen? The point is placeholder values mean you need *two* mistakes to cause a problem, not one. There's a responsible way to do this, and there's a reckless way.

Comment: @tadman - but still, there is no sql injection bug. It is a very bad practice and it's good to educate users. But not with lies.

Comment: @shaggy This is how SQL injection bugs happen: When you don't use prepared statements with placeholder values. That there isn't a bug *right now* in this *test code* is largely irrelevant. This is asking for trouble.

Comment: @tadman - "This code has some SQL injection bugs" vs "That there isn't a bug right now" - the first statement is what I call "lies".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside foreach loop try replacing the below code:

```
array_push($someArray, [$row['pilihan']   => $row['total']]);
```

to:

```
$someArray[$row['pilihan']] = $row['total'];
```

Comment: How to work with multiple data? like this

`$someArray[$row['pilihan']] = $row['total'],[$row['ex1']] = $row['ex2'];`